# How to interrupt an XSLT for-each loop for not contiguos elements?

Tags: xslt, foreach

I have a structured XML with this structure:

```
<root>
  <item/>
  <item/>
  <something/>
  <item/>
</root>
```

If I use something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/item">
```

it will pick all the `item` elements inside the list. I want to interrupt the loop after the second `item`, because between the 2nd and the 3rd there is a `something` element.

How can I get this?

Comment: didn't you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470045/how-to-break-a-for-each-loop-in-xslt ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually break out of a **xsl:for-each** loop. You need to construct your loop so as to select only the elements you want in the first place.

In this case, you want to select all **item** elements which don't have a preceding sibling that isn't also an **item** element.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/item[not(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::item)])]"> 
   <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

When this is used, it should only select the first two **item** elements.

Answer (score 0):

**In XSLT there isn't any possibility for a "break" out** of an `<xsl:for-each>` or out of `<xsl:apply-templates>`, except using `<xsl:message terminate="yes"/>` which you probably don't want. This is due to the fact that XSLT is a functional language and as in any functional language there isn't any concept of "order of execution" -- for example the code can be executing *in parallel* on all the nodes that are selected.

The solution is to specify in the `select` attribute an expression selecting *exactly* the wanted nodes.

**Use**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/*[not(self::item)][1]/preceding-sibling::*">
 <!-- Processing here -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

This selects for processing all preceding elements siblings of the first child element of the top element that isn't `item` -- that means the starting group of adjacent `item` elements that are the first children of the top element.