# How to break XSLT for-each loop?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I know break is not possible in XSLT for-each loop. 
But from following example, If I want to show 'something' element exist or not. Then I will go through loop and once I got it I want to break loop.

1. I will make one bool variable say isExist=false;
2. I will go through all nodes one by one.
3. Once I got 'something', I will change its value to isExist=true
4. want to break loop here.

Now I want to break loop bcoz I want to show status as true or false. But If I will not use break after step 3, it will go to loop and make change it to false and I will get status as false.

**My question is: If break not possible then How to achieve this result?**

I am following this link [How to interrupt an XSLT for-each loop for not contiguos elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531431/how-to-interrupt-an-xslt-for-each-loop-for-not-contiguos-elements)

According to this link I will get first two occurrence but it doen't say 'something' exist or not.

```
<root>
  <item/>
  <item/>
  <something/>
  <item/>
</root>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How-to break a for-each loop in XSLT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470045/how-to-break-a-for-each-loop-in-xslt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how variables work in XSLT - variables are always lexically scoped to their containing element, and once set they cannot be changed.

You need to learn to think more declaratively rather than procedurally - tell the processor *what* you want it to find rather than *how* you would look for it.  The XPath expression `boolean(/root/something)` will give you what you want - true if there is a `something` element as a child of the `root` and false otherwise.

Comment: Hi Ian, I have added new question which may understand my problem. link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247204/how-to-search-node-value-using-loop-in-xslt

Answer (score 3):

If all you're after is whether `<something/>` exists or not, you could also just check using

```
<xsl:if test="/root/something">
    // do fancy stuff...
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Hi Reinder, I have added new question which may understand my problem. link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247204/how-to-search-node-value-using-loop-in-xslt

Answer (score 2):

When you write a XSLT template that matches an element selector, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="entry"> .... </entry>
```

and you have a XML file like this one:

```
<entries>
    <entry number="345" type="A"/>
    <entry number="123" type="B"/>
    <entry number="334" type="A"/>
    <entry number="322" type="C"/>
</entries>
```

The XSLT template will be processed *for all `entry` elements*. So most of the time, you never need to use a `for-each` in XSLT. In the above example, the template will be processed 4 times, since there are 4 `entry` elements to match. Inside each one you can extract or print the data that's available in that context (such as the attributes, in this example).

You can usually also perform many conditional expressions without ever using an `<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:choose>`, by restricting what you need via XPath predicates.

If you add another template for the `entry` elements with a predicate like this:

```
<xsl:template match="entry[@type='A']"> .... </entry>
```

then it will *override* the `entry` templates *for the `entry` elements that have a `type` attribute with the value `A`*. The others will be processed by the template that has no predicate.

Giving preference to these tools, instead of `for-each`, `if` and `choose`, will help you think in a more functional oriented way and understand how to use XSLT better.

Since *variables* and *params* can't be changed, you can't use a regular for-loop to increment or decrement it, but in case you need one, it *is* possible to write a for loop that increments a variable in XSLT 1.0, but it has to be done recursively (using `xsl:call-template`). In this strategy, you don't assign a different value to a variable, but perform an operation *inside a variable block* which will set the final value for that variable.

See, for example, this stylesheet which calculates a factorial of a number. The param *n* in each recursion has a *final* value which doesn't change but is used as the data for another *n* param in the next recursion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:param name="number">5</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="fac">
            <xsl:call-template name="factorial">
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$number"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$fac"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="factorial">
        <xsl:param name="n"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$n &gt; 1">
                <xsl:call-template name="factorial">
                    <xsl:with-param name="n-1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:value-of select="$n * $n - 1"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You code return factorial as result. Can we use same way to find any value is exist or not in loop and return true if exist. Please check my question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247204/how-to-search-node-value-using-loop-in-xslt I want final output as true or false. Hopeful to get suggestion from you.

Comment: As I explained above, you can use predicates and you *don't need a loop to test existence*. XSLT is not the language if you should be using if you want to write a loop that exits when it matches a value.