# XSLT: How to exit a "for-each" loop if a condition is satisfied

Tags: xslt, foreach

How do I exit a "for-each" loop in XSL if a condition is satisfied?
e.g. Suppose I want the XSL to display the address of apartments which have (2 bedrooms and rent <= 1000), in the following XML, the following XSL code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//apartment/apartment_details">
  <xsl:if test="bedrooms=$bedrooms and rent &lt;= $budget "> 
    <!--display apartment address--> 
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

would return the same apartment address twice. I want to display the apartment address only once even if there are multiple  for the apartment that satisfy the condition.

XML structure:

```
<apartments>
  <apartment>
    <address>
        <street>....</street>
        <city>....</city>
    </address>
    <apartment_details>
        <bedrooms>2</bedrooms>
        <bathrooms>2</bathrooms>
        <rent>1000</rent>
    </apartment_details>
    <apartment_details>
        <bedrooms>2</bedrooms>
        <bathrooms>1</bathrooms>
        <rent>900</rent>
    </apartment_details>
    ...
  </apartment>
  ...
</apartments>
```

Thank you.

Comment: "even if there are multiple _____ for the apartment that satisfy the condition" - you seem to be missing a word.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470045/how-to-break-a-for-each-loop-in-xslt/8507243#8507243

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I exit a "for-each" loop in XSL if a condition is satisfied?

**This is not possible. There isn't any XSLT instruction for exiting the processing of `xsl:for-each` and continuing the execution of the transformation. What you can do is specify precisely the conditions that the selected nodes should meet**.

**Use**:

```
<xsl:for-each select=
 "/*/apartment
      [apartment_details[bedrooms=$bedrooms and $budget  >= rent]]">
  <!-- output apartment address here -->  
</xsl:for-each>
```

This code displays the address of any `apartment` that is a child of the top element of the XML document and that has an `apartment_details` child, for whose children `bedrooms` and `rent` it is `true()` that: `bedrooms=$bedrooms and $budget  >= rent`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would need to use a loop, instead try a filter expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="NODE[CRITERIA][1]">
```